# What is the best way to manage one's session variables?

Tags: session-variables

I am trying not to let my session variables balloon out of control, especially since some carry heavy objects.

In the application that I am developing, there are 3 major items that can be searched on; let's say, `people`, `cars`, and `pets`. Each has a search screen and results (stored in sessions) which can be sorted and paged. When I go to the details page of one of the items, I want to be able to easily go back to my search results. However, if I go to any other page, say I jump to pets or an `About Us` page, I want to kill the session variable I was just working on. However, I want to avoid a function at the beginning of each screen to do this. Is there a better way to manage one's session variables?

Comment: what tech are you using? php, jee etc?

Answer (score 0):

You could nest them in arrays:

```
$_SESSION['results'][$item_id]['results_thing'];
```

This is a pretty normal thing to do.  You will have to have some header that unsets variables.  That's unavoidable - in order to do something, you need some code.